# How can we change status bar color of screen having presentation:'modal' appears

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, statusbar

I am struggling to change the status bar color of screen which I am presenting in modal.

**Code:**

*Navigator file*

```
 <RootStack.Group
        screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            presentation:'modal',
            headerMode: 'none',
        }}>
        <RootStack.Screen
            name={'ScreenName'}
            component={ScreenComponent}/>
 </RootStack.Group>
```

***Actually what I want is this***

[image: The view I want]

***Currently the view looks like this***

[image: Current view]

**What I have tried:**

Setting the status bar properties in root stack.

```
 <RootStack.Group
        screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            presentation:'modal',
            headerMode: 'none',
            statusBar: {
                visible: true,
                backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                style: 'dark'
            }
        }}>
```

With in the component:

```
 <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="purple"
     barStyle="light-content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) instead. It can be transparent and its child could cover everything except a status bar. Something like this would work:

```
<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  transparent={true}
  visible={modalVisible}>
  <View style={styles.modal}>
...
  </View>
</Modal>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modal: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '10%',
    height: '90%',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderTopStartRadius: 10,
    borderTopEndRadius: 10,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2x `<SafeAreaView>` elements inside of the `<Modal>` element to change the colors of the StatusBar.  The first element will be empty, with a style of `style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: 'green' }}`, and will change the top StatusBar.  The second element will have your modal content inside and will have a style of `style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}`, and will change the bottom StatusBar.

Here is an example:

```
<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  presentationStyle='fullScreen'
  visible={modalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {
    Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  }}
>
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: '#191109', }} />
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#191109', }}>
    
    {/* modal content... */}
      
    <Pressable
      style={[styles.modalButton, styles.modalButtonClose]}
      onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
    >
      <Text
        style={styles. modalButtonText}
      >
        Close Modal
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  </SafeAreaView>
</Modal>
```

You can also do this with your main App to change the color of the status bars, just wrap the whole App in `<>` tags, and then put the two `<SafeAreaView>` elements inside, using the same pattern and styles, as seen in this second example below:

```
<>
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: '#191109' }}/>
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.appContainer} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
    {/* app content... */}
  </SafeAreaView>
</>
```